# Using AJAX to call the controller and download a file

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-boot

I am trying to download a file from the server side. I need to call the function using AJAX. I have tested if the download works without using AJAX, just testing the URL directly in the web browser, it works. But when I try to use AJAX, it executes the function but the response does not work.

CONTROLLER:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "descargaUsuaris", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    public final void descargaUsuaris(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ParseException {
        byte[] processedFile = getUsuaris();
         
        JSONObject output;
        try {
            output = new JSONObject(new String(processedFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            JSONArray docs = output.getJSONArray("data");

            File file = new File("temp/" + "temp_csv.csv");
            File file2 = new File("temp/" + "usuaris.csv");
            

            jsonToCsv(docs, file, file2);

            file.delete();
            ContentDisposition disposition = ContentDisposition.builder( "attachment" )
                    .filename( "taulaMatriculaEstudiant.csv", StandardCharsets.UTF_8 )
                    .build();
                response.setContentType( "text/csv" );
                response.setHeader( "Cache-Control", "no-cache" );
                response.setHeader( "Expires", "0" );
                response.setHeader( "Pragma", "no-cache" );

                OutputStream  out = response.getOutputStream();
                IOUtils.copy( new FileInputStream( file2.getAbsolutePath() ), out  ); // IOUtils from Apache Commons-IO
                out.flush();
                file2.delete();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            
            
        

    }
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function descargaUsuaris(data) {

    var url = "/9avaldoval/administracio/descargaUsuaris";
    var form = $('#formAdmBlue');
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function() {
            
        }


    });

}
```

Comment: `success: function() {}` - you're doing nothing with the response you have just received - where did you expect to "see" the data?

Comment: You're not doing anything with the response because you're not returning anything from the function because its a `void` If you want to do something with the response you'd return something from the method and add a variable `function(result)` in the success.

Comment: I get your point, but if my response is the IOUtils, what should I do to just download the file?